# Angular testing: Method returning an observable is successfully tested, but test coverage still marks it as noncovered statement

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, integration-testing, code-coverage

I want to test this method:

```
public getAll(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
    return this.$http.get<Array<Todo>>('http://5def6a2502b2d90014e1b38a.mockapi.io/api/v1/todos/');
}
```

I've written a test for this method:

```
it('should return array of todos', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const mockedValue = [new Todo('Test')];
    spyOn(service, 'getAll').and.returnValue(of(mockedValue));
    service.getAll().subscribe((value) => {
        expect(value).toBe(mockedValue);
        done();
    });
});
```

When i run `ng test`, this test is marked as successful, but code-coverage still marks it like an uncovered test:

[image]

Why? And how I can cover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the method you are trying to test. This is why the coverage says this is not tested.

With your test case you are only verifying that you mock works, but not that the function does what you expect it to do.

You should not mock `getAll` but rather mock the http client.

There is a [HttpClientTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule) exactly for those cases.

You would need to include this module in you TestBed

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [YourServiceUnderTest],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
});
```

with this setup you can write a test like this:

```
  it('getAll', () => {
    const mockResponse: Todo[] = [new Todo(1)];
    const service = TestBed.get(YourServiceUnderTest);
    const httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    service.getAll()
      .subscribe(data => {
        expect(data).toEqual(mockResponse);
      });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('YOUR-URI-GOES-HERE');

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    req.flush(mockCourse);
  });
```

Maybe have a look at those articles:

[Testing Http Requests](https://medium.com/better-programming/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf)

[Testing with HttpClient](https://alligator.io/angular/testing-httpclient/)